# Syncing table view with Fetch Result controller using core data

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a test case where I insert 100 items into a managed context. In another contact I have a fetch result controller where it updates a table view. When the insert call back comes from fetch result controller, I use

```
self.tableView.insertRows(at: <#T##[IndexPath]#>
```

and then commit changes. However when the data source delegate asks the same fetch result controller, instead of incrementing the items by one ( which I received in the call back, the fetch result controller has more than one insertion.

This causes *exception* from table view saying that number of inserted rows before update is not consistent with ones after.

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Contact means context? Your "(" does not close

Comment: Use **only** the insert/delete lines in the delegate methods of the fetched results controller.

Comment: I found the issue, when having a fetch result controller you have to make sure it is connected to a managed context where it uses the main thread and not  background thread.